# PHP and MySql - How can I make this insert query work?

Tags: php, mysql

So this is my code:

```
public function cadastrar(Family $family){

        var_dump($family); //just to verify


        $objDb = new db_con();
        $conn = $objDb->getConn();

        //REGISTER FAMILY INTO DATABASE
        $sql = "insert into family(family_declaracao_renda,
                                    familia_renda_mensal,
                                    family_assinatura_local,
                                    family_assinatura_dia,
                                    family_assinatura_mes,
                                    family_assinatura_ano,
                                    family_deficiente_presente,
                                    family_adaptacao_necessaria_imovel)
                            values( '$family->getDeclaracaoRendaFamiliar()',
                                    '$family->getRendaBrutaMensal()',
                                    '$family->getAssinaturaLocal()',
                                    '$family->getAssinaturaDia()',
                                    '$family->getAssinaturaMes()',
                                    '$family->getAssinaturaAno()',
                                    '$family->getDeficientePresente()',
                                    '$family->getAdaptacaoImovelNecessaria()')";

        //Executar query
        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
            echo 'SUCCESS!';
        } else {
            echo 'ERROR!';
        }

    }
```

So I know that you can put variables in between *VALUES('variable1', 'variable2')*. I'm calling class methods from this object, what am I missing?

Comment: you cannot call function inside string `'$family->getDeclaracaoRendaFamiliar()'` use dot to concat or use variables.

Comment: Use prepared statements.

Comment: also  you can use `{}` like this `values('{$family->getDeclaracaoRendaFamiliar()'}`

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha - you go an apostrophe in the wrong place `()'}` should be `()}'`  That is my preferred syntax when interpolating method calls.  It's shorter then `".`.  For the OP as others said don't concatenate, prepare your queries.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix yes my mistake thanks.

Comment: Your number of fields / values is wrong, you have 7 fields, and 8 values.  Which is just one reason your query doesn't work. `'$family->getDeclaracaoRendaFamiliar()'` is the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prepare your query, Its the best way to secure your DB against SQLInjection type attacks.  It also takes care of a lot of quoting issues, and other things.

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO family(
    family_declaracao_renda,
    familia_renda_mensal,
    family_assinatura_local,
    family_assinatura_dia,
    family_assinatura_mes,
    family_assinatura_ano,
    family_deficiente_presente,
    family_adaptacao_necessaria_imovel
)VALUES(
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?
)';
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param(
    $stmt,
    'ssssssss', //must be the same as number of argments, types s=string, i=int, d=double/float, b=blob 
    $family->getDeclaracaoRendaFamiliar(),
    $family->getRendaBrutaMensal(),
    $family->getAssinaturaLocal(),
    $family->getAssinaturaDia(),
    $family->getAssinaturaMes(),
    $family->getAssinaturaAno(),
    $family->getDeficientePresente(),
    $family->getAdaptacaoImovelNecessaria()
);

//Executar query
if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
    echo 'SUCCESS!';
} else {
    echo 'ERROR!';
}
```

It's not hard, even if the MySqli procedural interface is crap.  Consider using the Object oriented interface, or switch to PDO (my preferred). MySqli's OOP interface, is a bit easier but I won't go into covering it just for the sake of length. You can look it up on PHP.net, or I am sure there are some tutorials out there.

One word of warning I haven't used MySqli in several years (maybe 6-8) and the procedural style even longer. So I can't gurantee that will work exactly as I have it here. In fact I don't think I ever did use the procedural style of MySqli. When I moved away from `mysql_` (so I could do prepared statements) was right around the middle run of PHP5.3 (2010ish maybe a year after I finished web-design college), and I was getting into using OOP (classes and object) almost exclusively in my code.  So most of the `mysqli` code I just copied from `PHP.net`.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

In PDO:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO family(
    family_declaracao_renda,
    familia_renda_mensal,
    family_assinatura_local,
    family_assinatura_dia,
    family_assinatura_mes,
    family_assinatura_ano,
    family_deficiente_presente,
    family_adaptacao_necessaria_imovel
)VALUES(
    :family_declaracao_renda,
    :familia_renda_mensal,
    :family_assinatura_local,
    :family_assinatura_dia,
    :family_assinatura_mes,
    :family_assinatura_ano,
    :family_deficiente_presente,
    :family_adaptacao_necessaria_imovel
)';
try{
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);
    $Pdo->prepare($sql)->execute([
        ':family_declaracao_renda'          => $family->getDeclaracaoRendaFamiliar(),
       ':familia_renda_mensal'              => $family->getRendaBrutaMensal(),
       ':family_assinatura_local'           => $family->getAssinaturaLocal(),
       ':family_assinatura_dia'             => $family->getAssinaturaDia(),
       ':family_assinatura_mes'             => $family->getAssinaturaMes(),
       ':family_assinatura_ano'             => $family->getAssinaturaAno(),
       ':family_deficiente_presente'        => $family->getDeficientePresente(),
       ':family_adaptacao_necessaria_imovel'=> $family->getAdaptacaoImovelNecessaria(),
    ]);
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "PDOException[{$e->getCode()}] {$e->getMessage()} in {$e->getFile()} on {$e->getLine()}";
}
```

In PDO you can use named place holders `:name` instead of `?` as MySqli uses (you can still use the `?` in PDO).  What I typically do is copy the field names and add `:` to the front of them. Named placeholders make it easy to keep track of what value goes where, and the order of the data array (used in `execute` doesn't even matter). As you can see the `mysqli` version took around 4 calls, the PDO version took only 2, and with method chaining `$Pdo->prepare($sql)->execute(...)` you don't even need to put it on another line or set a local variable.  That is equivalent to this:

```
 //$Pdo->prepare($sql)->execute(...)
 $stmt = $Pdo->prepare($sql); //returns PDOStatement
 $stmt->execute(...); //makes a call on PDOStatement
```

Because `$Pdo->prepare($sql)` returns a `PDOStatement` if we don't need that object for anything else, we can just call `->execute(...)` on the return value of the previous method in the chain. I felt I should explain that as you may not be used to using Objects.  But, chaining keeps the code tidy (no superfluous variables) which makes it bit easier to keep track things (there are less things, to keep track of).

In short, its very easy to do it in both MySqli & PDO, but PDO is well worth learning how to use as it has many advantages. Better interface, better fetch methods, named placeholders, exceptions etc...

Cheers!

Comment: Please re check, OP's no. of fields / values is correct => 8/8

Comment: @JaswinderSingh - yup your right, not sure how I missed that one, lol, tired I guess. Anyway I fixed the answer.  I also moved some things around and cleaned a few things up, yada yada. ... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO family(
    family_declaracao_renda,
    familia_renda_mensal,
    family_assinatura_local,
    family_assinatura_dia,
    family_assinatura_mes,
    family_assinatura_ano,
    family_deficiente_presente,
    family_adaptacao_necessaria_imovel
)VALUES(
    :family_declaracao_renda,
    :familia_renda_mensal,
    :family_assinatura_local,
    :family_assinatura_dia,
    :family_assinatura_mes,
    :family_assinatura_ano,
    :family_deficiente_presente,
    :family_adaptacao_necessaria_imovel
)';
try{
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);
    $Pdo->prepare($sql)->execute([
        ':family_declaracao_renda'          => $family->getDeclaracaoRendaFamiliar(),
       ':familia_renda_mensal'              => $family->getRendaBrutaMensal(),
       ':family_assinatura_local'           => $family->getAssinaturaLocal(),
       ':family_assinatura_dia'             => $family->getAssinaturaDia(),
       ':family_assinatura_mes'             => $family->getAssinaturaMes(),
       ':family_assinatura_ano'             => $family->getAssinaturaAno(),
       ':family_deficiente_presente'        => $family->getDeficientePresente(),
       ':family_adaptacao_necessaria_imovel'=> $family->getAdaptacaoImovelNecessaria(),
    ]);
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "PDOException[{$e->getCode()}] {$e->getMessage()} in {$e->getFile()} on {$e->getLine()}";
}
```